# powershell out-file how to rid of extra spaces on each line

Tags: powershell, file-io, removing-whitespace

I run this command and I get all computer hostnames in the names.txt file.
Each hostname in the file is on a separate line, but every hostname is followed with white spaces which cause an issue when I try to read this file. How can I output to this file without getting the white spaces on each line?

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Select-Object -property name | Sort-Object -Property name | out-file -filepath C:\temp\names.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

You have the problem that you don't just have names, you have objects with the property 'name', and you also have the problem that `Out-File` runs complex objects through some kind of formatting before sending them to the file.

To fix both, expand the name out to just text, and generally use `Set-Content` instead:

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Sort-Object | Set-Content C:\temp\names.txt
```

or in short form

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * | Select -Expand Name | Sort | sc C:\temp\names.txt
```

or

```
(Get-ADComputer -filter *).Name | sort | sc C:\temp\names.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown of the short forms. I didn't know the dot operator was the same as select-object!

Answer (score 0):

Piping it through this should work (before piping to the out-file):

**EDIT**: Piping through `% { $_.name }` should convert @{name=VALUE} to VALUE:

```
 % { $_ -replace ' +$','' } | % { $_.name }
```

Like this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Select-Object -property name | Sort-Object -Property name | % { $_ -replace ' +$','' } | % { $_.name } | out-file -filepath C:\temp\names.txt
```

Comment: not working..getting something like @{name=AWS-TESTSERVER1} instead of AWS-TESTSEVER1

Comment: I think that should do the trick.  It is returning a hashtable where `name=VALUE`, so you can do foreach and select the key: `%{ $_.name }`

Comment: I think the regex is incorrect. Try `\s+$` instead.

Answer (score 0):

expandproperty should get rid of the @()

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | sort Name | Select -expandproperty Name | %{ $_.TrimEnd(" ") } | out-file -filepath C:\temp\names
```

Untested no AD@home